# AngularJS loading data returned by $http in datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I am using JQuery Datatables in my AJS app to load data retrieved from an $http GET request. I've tried searching for any example on how to load data retrieved through my AJS app - Service > $http GET call into datatable but couldn't find any. So does anyone know how I can do that? Any info, examples or problem related resources are highly appreciated. Thanks

Note: Data retrieved from the $http GET call is in the following format:

```
[{"_id":"543e58b862744980197026a8","title":"Mr.","firstName":"Michael","lastName":"A","email":"michael@gmail.com","address":"New York","password":"123456","activeMember":true,"__v":0,"role":"Member","memberSince":"2014-10-15T11:21:28.884Z"},{"_id":"543e591862744980197026a9","title":"Ms","firstName":"Mary","lastName":"W","email":"mary@gmail.com","address":"New York","password":"123456","activeMember":true,"__v":0,"role":"Admin","memberSince":"2014-10-15T11:23:04.382Z"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming datatable that you use is this: http://www.datatables.net/. In that case, I suggest you to use angular to fetch data from server and build the table. After that pass the html table id to jquery datatable.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    // load data from array as example
    $scope.items = [{
        firstName: 'foo',
        lastName: 'bar'
    }, {
        firstName: 'buzz',
        lastName: 'booo'
    }, {
        firstName: 'zxzz',
        lastName: 'yyy'
    }, 
    ];

}]);    
    //Use this to get data from server             
    /*
    $http.get('url').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
    */

// pass to jquery data table 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

See the approach in action http://jsfiddle.net/6wqk35na/